# Are there probiotics for upper respiratory tract tissue?

Tags: infection, immune-system, lungs

If the lungs can be subject to bacterial infection, why do there not exist beneficial probiotics that live in lung tissue to combat "bad" bacteria proliferation?

Comment: There's no such thing as beneficial bacteria in the lungs.

Comment: So basically lungs in a good state are completely clear of all bacteria?

Comment: The lungs aren't sterile, but they're nothing at all like the GI tract. Very few bacteria and at least to my knowledge none of them are considered beneficial.

Comment: After doing a little more reading I'm upvoting your question and retracting my first comment. I don't think we know if there are beneficial bacteria in the lungs but it's entirely possible there are. My comment was based on the (outdated) concept that the lungs are a sterile environment.

Comment: However, it would be expected on this site for you to do some prior research. Adding a link to a reputable source to your question that discusses bacteria found in the lung would improve it greatly (and is required, actually).

Comment: I don't understand the question --- the OP asks about URT microbiome or lung microbiom? The title is different than end question.

Comment: @JohnDoea I take it to be about the lungs, not URT, but it would be good for OP to clarify that.